# Getting available time slots in Lightning Scheduler

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, field-service-lightning, lightning-scheduler

When creating a Service Appointment in Lightning Scheduler there is no standard validation to prevent from booking a Service Resource multiple times during the same time slot.

How can we get available time slots for a Service Resource in Lightning Scheduler and allow for booking a Service Resource only once per time slot?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to break the fundamental of reserving a time slot to a particular service resource. Is this an internal or external booking? Are your time slots configured by the hour? Do you have some of the advanced features turned on such as time blocking before and after that may affect this?

See here for more advanced features for the Lightning Scheduler setup.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.ls_manage_settings.htm&type=5